# Python not reading input image clearly

Tags: python, image, project, tesseract

I am trying to build a project and it needs python to read an image(marksheet specifically) but it is not clearly reading it and i am getting a lot of garbage
Can it be fixed? If so then how??
I tried using OCR and then i tried extracting the table from the marksheet itself but it does not seem to work

```
from img2table.document import Image
from img2table.ocr import TesseractOCR
ocr = TesseractOCR(lang = 'eng')
img = Image(src = '1.jpeg')
img_tables = img.extract_tables(ocr=ocr)
img.to_xlsx("test.xlsx",ocr = ocr)
```

Where 1.jpeg is a jpeg image of a marksheet in the same directory

Comment: As a side note I used easyocr instead of TesseractOCR and I got far better results .. no garbage ... not perfect yet but you should have a try.

Comment: how looks your maksheet image? Without an examplee and a clear  complaint we can't help you.